# Unity поддержка соотношения 18/9

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте, использую Unity 2017.3.1 personal. Делаю билд пустого проекта запускаю на эмуляторе Pixel 2XL и наблюдаю внизу жирную, черную рамку. Как её убрать? Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем решил проблему следующим образом: экспортировал проект в Android Studio, зашел в res/values/stules изменил тему на default и все стало в порядке. Похоже Unity по стоку ставит тему конфликтующую с устройствами на Android Oreo и экраном 16/9. Что интересно, на Android Nougat 7.1.1 и экраном 16/9 все было в порядке. Всем спасибо за ответы!)

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто, не надо ничего никуда портировать. В Player Settings/Resolution and Presentation/Aspect Ratio Mode меняете на Custom